# How to Resolve "User Location Not Supported" Error When Connecting to palm2 API from Server in Amsterdam?

Tags: vps, google-api-key-restrictions, palm-api

I'm encountering an issue when trying to connect to the palm2 API. When I make a request to the API from my local machine, I receive valid responses without any problems. However, when I attempt to connect to the same API from a server located in Amsterdam, I consistently receive the following error message:
`{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "User location is not supported for the API use.", "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION" } }`
It seems like the API is restricting access based on user location, and it's not allowing connections from the Amsterdam server. I suspect that the issue might be related to the server's IP address being flagged or blocked by the API.

I've researched a bit and found that using a proxy could potentially help in situations like this, by masking the server's location and making it appear as if the request is coming from a different location. However, before I proceed with this approach, I wanted to gather some insights from the community.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue when trying to access an API that enforces location-based restrictions?

If using a proxy could be a potential solution, what are the best practices for setting up a proxy to route the requests from the Amsterdam server to the palm2 API?

Are there any other strategies or approaches I should consider to bypass this "User location is not supported" error and successfully connect to the API from the Amsterdam server?

Comment: Try VPN its not available in the EU until later this year.

Answer (score 3):

You're right with your intuition of needing proxies for this, it seems like you're facing geo-location blocks. While I have not used the  palm2 API, these geo-location blocks are actually pretty common. The best strategy for incorporating proxies would be making use of residential proxies (these make use of IPs from real residential users, and will serve your needs better than datacenter proxies), and maybe rotating them depending on if you need to change locations.

###### Reference: [Datacenter Proxies Vs. Residential Proxies: A deep dive comparison](https://get.brightdata.com/gm-differences-between-datacenter-and-residential-proxies?sid=c001)

Answer (score 0):

The list of supported regions is [available here](https://developers.generativeai.google/available_regions). You'll need to ensure your requests are restricted to these source locations.